# Facebook Oauth URL Blocked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm currently testing my Ruby on Rails project Omniauth with Facebook functionality and no how I enter my Redirect URI it fails.

[image]

The exact error is:
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

If I do,

https://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback

it then complains about trying to an ssl certificate to a non ssl puma. Are there any suggestions for this issue? Perhaps, working on my SSL certificates or any other solution.

I've been looking into similar posts and nothing has solved this issue. Please advise.

Comment: `localhost` should not require HTTPS. And the message behind that red x even says that localhost redirect URIs should not need entering at all. What exactly _is_ the redirect URI actually used?

Comment: The URI is http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback which triggers that message that it shouldn't be entered at all. Ok.....if I then leave the space blank since localhost shouldn't be entered. I get the same error message.

Comment: I think I remember Facebook has certain issues with such URLs, that are not using the default ports.